# My pointer is changing address erroneously

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a very simple C program. My program uses a very simple hash file I created. Here is my hash file:

```
const int SIZE = 26;

// A is 65 through Y is 89
int get_index(char key) {
   return ((int) key) - 65;
}

void reset_hash(int* hash) {
   int i = 0;
   for (; i < (SIZE - 1); i++) {
      hash[i] = 0;
   }
   hash[SIZE -1] = '\0';
}

int get_value(int* hash, char key) {
   return hash[get_index(key)];
}

void increment_value(int* hash, char key, int value) {
   hash[get_index(key)] = ++value;
}
```

If absolutely necessary, I can explain why my hash function is so simple. I did not deem that necessary at this point but I can tell you that my domain is very simple and constant, that is why this hashing algorithm works well.

Now, the hash is created once from the main of another file:

```
int* hash = calloc(SIZE_OF_AC, sizeof(int));
```

and the following operations are called from the same file in various orders:

```
reset_hash(hash);
get_value(hash, /* some character here */);
increment_value(hash, /* some character here */, value);
```

I am also passing the hash pointer around several times, and the two main target functions receive the hash argument as follows:

```
int* hash
```

The calling function just sends `hash`.

Now, I am printing the address of `hash` using:

```
printf("hash: %p\n", hash);
```

In one place in my main file, but is printed several times because the function is executed several times. Here is the output that I receive:

```
hash: 0x801010
hash: 0x801010
hash: 0x3100000000801010
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My question is, why is the address of my hash seem to change? Under what conditions in c would the starting address of an int* change given the operations I declared above?

I apologize if you think that I am missing more vital information. Let me know and I will post more. Thank you for any response.

Comment: Probably you're corrupting memory somewhere, overwriting `hash`.

Comment: You're on a 64-bit system, yes? `0x801010` looks like it could be a valid heap address. `0x3100000000801010` has exactly the same low-order 32 bits, but with `0x31` in the high-order byte. `0x31` is the ASCII code for the digit `'1'`. (Note that it's not the *address* of the `int*` that's changing, it's the *value*, i.e., .the address that it points to).

Comment: What is the data structure immediately behind and ahead of `hash`?

Comment: Why not just `return key - 'A'`?

Comment: You guys are right. Something else was stepping over my hash pointer. To prove that, I declared the hash as a global array and the error went away. I am assuming this is because the array does not use a separate pointer to element 0, and it sits in the global section of the stack. I still have to debug my program and find out who the offending element is. Thank you for the useful comments!

Comment: if you want proper help, you'll need to post code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The index func seems to have an error no?

```
// A is 65 through Y is 89
int get_index(char key) {
   return ((int) key) - 65;
}
```

Should it be (int) (key - 65)?

Comment: That's the same.  Even just `return key - 65;` would be the same.

Comment: And if you mean `'A'`, write `'A'`, not `65`.